# PL/SQL noob syntax Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am very new to PL/SQL (no I mean a real noob with it as in started learning it today) and have been trying out some simple scripts using the TOAD IDE but have become a little stuck with this one. I am simply trying to loop through a series of records using a cursor and display each one but keep getting the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 13, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

My code is as follows:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    CURSOR cursor1 IS 
    SELECT TWOR_WORKS_ID
    FROM TMA_WORKS
    WHERE TWOR_ORG_REF = 9999;

BEGIN
    FOR records IN cursor1  
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line (records.TWOR_WORKS_ID);
        END LOOP;
END
```

Could someone please point out where I am going wrong as I have seen a few examples and the code looks the same as what I am trying. I am guessing it is a missing ; going off the error message but where?

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive and online.  Find the PL/SQL Reference here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm  Please learn to use it, rather than flooding SO with trivial syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was not aware of this reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need a `;` after `END`.

Comment: Thanks. As well as that I found that because I was running it as a script I also needed to add a / after the semi colon in order to make it execute the block and display my output rather than compile it and then discard it.